# are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#

I can't figure out this error in visual c#.

```
Error   1
'Engine.VerticalMenu' does not contain a definition for '_buttons' and no extension method '_buttons' accepting a first argument of type 'Engine.VerticalMenu' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

For this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, _menu._buttons.Count.ToString());
```

I have two projects, first one is Engine with same namespace Engine and of type class library, and the other one is windows form app that uses this Engine library. I have both using directives and references to project, what could possibly be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: The `Engine.VerticalMenu` class does not expose a `_buttons` property, so `_menu._buttons` is invalid.

Comment: Is `_buttons` a private member?  If so, you cannot access from outside of the class it is defined in.

Comment: @cdhowie, I think the error message would be different (something like *`_buttons` is inaccessible due to its protection level*) if `_buttons` was defined but `private`.

Comment: it is public guys, see comment below

Comment: @pokoko, just a jab in the dark, but... is your `Engine` assembly up-to-date? Can you rebuild it and check if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Here is some code http://pastebin.com/p3dK75WM. line 239 is problem

Comment: Is VerticalMenu class in the same assembly as its calling code (StartMenuState  class)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `_buttons` is private class member, so you can't access it from the outside.

Either make it public, or even better add public getter to the class of `_menu`:

```
public TypeOfButtonCollectionHere Buttons { get { return _buttons; } }
```

And change the calling code to:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, _menu.Buttons.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: So something else is wrong. Post more code in your question - how each class is defined and how each relevant member is defined.

Comment: What happens when you just comment that one line causing the error?

Comment: I created a new win form app and I copied plain text file after file. Same for the library. Then I included references to ALL assemblies needed from BOTH projects. I no longer get that error.

I can't tell what was wrong but this fixed it. Thank you all.

Comment: Cheers, you probably referenced old version of the class or something like that.

Comment: It might have been this: "If your application targets the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, you can add a reference to a class library that targets the .NET Framework 4 as long as that library does not reference any assemblies not included in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. If the library does include references to assemblies not in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, then Visual Studio will display an error message."

Answer (score 1):

Is _buttons possibly private? Then it is not visible outside of the menu class and you can't access it. Wrap it to a public property and you can access it.

Comment: This is the member in VerticalMenu: public List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();

Comment: @pokoko, are you positive that `VerticalMenu` class is the one used by your code (`Engine.VerticalMenu`)? Maybe you have several classes named `VerticalMenu` in different namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a naming conflict (namespace or class). Have you tried using the fully qualified name for the class? Without more information this is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not the public thing, vs has other errormessages for that. It looks like _menu doesn't have a member _buttons at all. So this means either the class or the interface _menu is of doesnt have _buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Check that *all* the assemblies referenced by the project Engine is also referenced by your Win form.

It would usually give another error if that's the case but not always.
If they are all referenced. Try a rebuild of just the Engine project. VS might throw the mentioned error if there's a compilation error in a referenced project. Those errors should show up in the error log, so you could also check the error log to see if there are other errors some of which is in engine.
(Even if that's not the case I would personally still build Engine alone, to completely rule it out)

Comment: seems you were right, thanks for pointing me in the right direction